# Inconsistent formatting and styling in my Applications page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, se-applications

(*Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, and Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64*)

This is what I see when I visit: User -> Settings -> Applications...

[image]

- The text formatting is inconsistent: The first item on my list (Stack Exchange API Documentation) is indented with the title in line with the icon, whereas the other two are left-aligned with their icons on separate lines.
- The positioning of the "Remove" button is inconsistent, and its text extends beyond its border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been addressed in the latest production build.

The description of our apps now wrap cleanly and consistently.

[image]

Comment: Now all that is left to do is to upload a square image for SEDE.