# Please make the positioning of the "Remove" button consistent on the applications settings

Tags: feature-request, design, responsive-design, se-applications

You can grant access to different "applications" to make use of your profile. One such example is Winter Bash, or metasmoke a.k.a. [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/).

[image]

Theoretically you should be able to revoke/remove this access, but that [has been broken for a while now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370293/removing-granted-access-to-an-application-is-no-longer-working).

What bugs me is the inconsistent placing of the button. Can we please align it to the right, regardless if it is on its own row or not?

Comment: Already reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374340/295232) I guess?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The site settings section of user preferences is now fully responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369930/282094) - That Feedback (answer) is the earliest exact duplicate.